# How to underline words in a string that also appear in a dictionary. PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

Hi I have a a string containing multiple words (about 26) and some of them will be real words which appear in a dictionary, others will just be rubbish.

What I need is for the computer to go through this string that has been outputted to the user, and underline, or highlight the real words.

I am using PHP, and the string will be different every time, and I already have a dictionary in txt format, that I have imported into the PHP and split up into an array, this is where the real words should come from.

Comment: What have you tried so far, how does your code look like, where did you fail?

Answer (score 2):

If there is punctuation, you may want to remove it first using a regular expression.

```
$sentence = 'ajhfd dog bba food!';
$clean_sentence = preg_replace ('/[^0-9a-z\s]/', '', $sentence);
```

You can use the explode function to split the words into an array.

```
$words = explode(' ', $clean_sentence);
```

And then you can go through the words and see if they are in your dictionary.

```
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (in_array($word, $dictionary)) {
        // This is a dictionary word, lets highlight it
        $sentence = preg_replace("/\b$word\b/", "<b>$word</b>", $sentence);
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't think about punctuaction. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

You break out each string into an array of words using explode() by space. You can do the same for the text file with new lines. Then loop through each value in the array you made from your string and use in_array() to check if the value is in the dictionary array. If it's true, you can assign an `<span class="dict_word">$value</span>` or something like that and just style for that that class.

This sounds like homework so I'm not going to write the code for you.